# java hibernate aggregation error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
qty|price
1 | 4
4 | 5
6 | 4
2 | 3
1 | 2
```

are entries on the database. i am trying to get the result: (group quantity by price)

```
qty|price
7 | 4
4 | 5
2 | 3
1 | 2
```

I am successful when i do this query using sqlwave to my local databse

> SELECT price, sum(quantity) FROM table

but when I try this in java/hibernate.. and try to list, i don't get the results for sum() aggregation. i tried aggregation.. but it gives me the sum of all the quantities instead of by price. How do i restrict so I get the sum of the quantity for specific price??

Here's my method:

```
protected void listInventory(String productID)
{
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try{
tx = session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT price, sum(quantity) FROM table WHERE product_code=:productID GROUP BY price");

query.setParameter("product_code",productID);

List iv = query.list();
for(Iterator iterator = iv.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
Products pb = (Products)iterator.next();
System.out.println("Price: "+pb.getPrice());
System.out.println("Quantity: " + pb.getQuantity());
}
tx.commit();
}catch (HibernateException e) {
       if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    }finally {
           session.close();serverWriter.flush(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your specific HQL/JPQL query and how you're reading it, along with the Hibernate-generated SQL.

Comment: @chrylis updated. I know pb.getQuantity() will only get the quantity for that specific entry.. so I am wondering how I can place the aggregated sum of qty for that price to be placed there instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of the quantity for a specific price, then you syntactically correct SQL.  Your expression:

```
SELECT price, sum(quantity) as quantity
FROM table;
```

Is not correct because there is no `group by` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT price, sum(quantity) as quantity
FROM table
GROUP BY price;
```

If you only want the results for one price:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity
FROM table
WHERE price = xxx;
```

Comment: the price is grouping, but the quantity is not displaying

Comment: @user2556304 . . . I don't know what `pb.getQuantity()` is.  Perhaps aliasing `sum()` to `quantity` will fix the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by aliasing sum to quantity? you mean "AS" can you please give an example of how to do this?

Comment: @user2556304 . . . Yes, that is what I mean.  `as` in the `select` clause gives a column or expression another name; the name is called a column alias.

Comment: Tried this. Error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.domain.net.Inventory